# How to add dynamic country name in all menu url in cake PHP?

Tags: cakephp

I want to use current session country name in all menu url and this is only for showing purpose in url

suppose current country is north-corea

current url is  http://localhost/project-name/*products/business_verticals*

and i want  in

url is  http://localhost/project-name/***north-corea***/products/business_verticals

and north-corea only for showing not used it for page.

i have country name in this session $_SESSION["csite"].... i want to use this session value to all menu url.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25643517/3576412

Answer (score 0):

```
Try:
Add code on routes.php
$currentPath = Router::getPaths(true);
$currentUrl = '';
if (!empty($currentPath->query['url'])) {
    $currentUrl = trim($currentPath->query['url']);
} elseif (!empty($currentPath->url)) {
    $currentUrl = trim($currentPath->url);
}

if (!empty($currentUrl)) {
    $currentUrlArr = explode('/', trim($currentUrl, "/"));
    if ($currentUrlArr[0] == 'north-corea') {
        Router::connect('/*', array('controller' => $currentUrlArr[1], 'action' => $currentUrlArr[2]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cakephp natively supports what it calls url prefixes. They are loaded in the routes.php config file and then can be used elsewhere in your app. To construct a url with a give prefix as in your example you would do

```
[ 'controller' => 'products', 'action' => 'business-verticals', 'north-corea' => true ]
```

Comment: may be u are right... but m not much good in cake php.... 

i want to show you http://interactivebees.net/vantage-security/europe  here is right top dropped down.... i want these drooped down in url...